# C++ augmenting an STL data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, tree, red-black-tree

My requirement is to be able to quickly retrieve a minimum and maximum value in a tree. (Note, not the minimum/maximum key, but min/max of the satellite data).

The tree would be based on strings as keys and each node would store an integer with it. This integer bound to change and be constantly updated. Keys remain fixed

I was considering using an approach described [here](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Rolf_Karlsson/lect3.pdf) of augmenting a red black tree, so that every node stores the maximum ( max of left's max and right's max and itself) similar for minimum.

So when I update a node, I would simply update the min/max of every node which was traversed to reach my current node.

What would be the best approach to avoid rewriting the STL implementation of red/black tree.

Comment: `boost` multi index container?

Comment: @Yakk thanks for the suggestion. Will do the job, but seems to be a bit of overkill, since I don't need the secondary index to be sorted, I just need to keep track of min/max sort of like a min/max heap

Comment: "You can't always get what you want.  You can't always get what you want.  But if you try some times, you get what you need." As an alternative, you can write your own multi index to augment boost adding the one that just supports min/max element (priority queue?), but that is lots of work, and do you really care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an STL container (e.g. `set`, which doesn't technically even need to me a BST as far as I know), as it doesn't provide you with access to the underlying structure.

Your options are:

- As you already mentioned, writing your own BST.
- Simply using a secondary BST (or heap) which is ordered by your integer value.
- Using Boost's [`multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort).